# Horizontal Nav not working in Microsoft Edge/IE

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a school project, and I have a nav bar that works fine in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, etc. However, it's not displaying properly on Edge or IE. This is how it is supposed to look:

[image]

Here is how it looks on Edge/IE:

[image]

```css
nav {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 1em 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #f3a368;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 609px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
}

nav li {
  float: left;
}

nav li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  line-height: 28px;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="portal.html">Portal</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `display: flex` in `ul`:

```
nav ul {
  display: flex;
  ...
}
```

More detail: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp